# using http to invoke my apache webservice on android

Tags: android, database, web-services, http, servlets

I'm working on an android application which allows users to create accounts on a database via my tomcat webservice. I've tested the webservice with a browser and it works fine. So I've tried to use make Http requests to that URL with my andriod app but it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
try{

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI webservice = new URI("http://my-machine-ip:8080/Login/login?username=jimmy&password=javajava");
        request.setURI(webservice);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);            
    }catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also set the internet permission. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Checking my log I have a connection error

```
05-31 17:46:50.299: W/System.err(17395): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.0.3:8080 timed out

enter code here
```

Comment: Check your apache server request log to see request actually came in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was a connection problem caused my my firewall. A quick reconfiguration of applications with access on the firewall has solved everything

Answer (score 0):

use your response object to get `getEntity().getStatusLine()` then get `getStatusCode()` and `getReasonPhrase()`.

Check that the status is `200` and the reason is `OK`.

Comment: you have "        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);            
" then use your response object call final int httpStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); final String responsePhrase = response().getSTatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

Comment: i typed in plain editor, may have typos, but you get the idea right

Comment: Yes, I get it. Apparently I'm getting a org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /my-machine-ip:8080 timed out error.

Comment: try from ur bower of your simulator/device to see it works or not. to see if the connection problem or your programming problem